# how to get the output in array using echo php

Tags: php, arrays

Hi in the below I am printing the group name using echo function.But I want to return the echo message in the form of array.Because these echo message I am reading in client side.
for example my output coming like this:

```
NewGroup-->New is one groupname and Group is the second groupname
```

Excepted output:

```
{New},{Group}
```

**php**

```
case "DispalyGroupDetails" :
    $userId = authenticateUser($db, $username, $password);

    if ($userId != NULL) {

        if (isset($_REQUEST['username'])) {
            $username = $_REQUEST['username'];

            $sql = "select Id from users where username='$username' limit 1";

            if ($result = $db -> query($sql)) {
                if ($row = $db -> fetchObject($result)) {

                    $sql = "SELECT g.id,g.groupname
                            FROM `users` u, `friends` f, `group` g
                            WHERE u.Id=f.providerId and                   
                            f.providerId=g.providerId
                            GROUP BY g.id, g.groupname";

                    $theResult = $db -> query($sql);

                    if ($theResult) {

                        while ($theRow = $db -> fetchObject($theResult)) {

                            echo $theRow -> groupname;

                        }
                        $out = SUCCESSFUL;
                    } else {
                        $out = FAILED;
                    }

                } else {
                    $out = FAILED;
                }
            } else {
                $out = FAILED;
            }
        } else {
            $out = FAILED;
        }
    } else {
        $out = FAILED;
    }
    break;
```

Comment: try echo json_encode($array);

Comment: agree with @john echo json_encode($theRow);

Comment: how to print only single row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the group name into an array, then `json_encode($array);`.

NOTE: this code is not tested as I do not have your database.

like this:

```
 $userId = authenticateUser($db, $username, $password);
 $array = array();
    if ($userId != NULL) {

        if (isset($_REQUEST['username'])) {               
             $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
             $sql = "select Id from users where username='$username' limit 1";

             if ($result = $db->query($sql)) {
                    if ($row = $db->fetchObject($result)) {    
                        $sql = "SELECT g.id,g.groupname FROM `users` u, `friends` f, `group` g WHERE u.Id=f.providerId and f.providerId=g.providerId GROUP BY g.id, g.groupname";
                        $theResult = $db->query($sql);
                        if ($theResult) {
                    $count = 0;
                    while( $theRow = $db->fetchObject($theResult)) {  
                        $array[$count] = $theRow->groupname;
                        $count++;
                    }
                        $out = SUCCESSFUL;
                        echo json_encode($array);
                        } else {
                            $out = FAILED;
                        }

                    } else {
                        $out = FAILED;                      
                    }
             } else {
                    $out = FAILED;
             }              
        } else {
                $out = FAILED;
        }           
    }
    else {
        $out = FAILED;
    }
```

Comment: My output coming like this [New,Group] how to read this value in android

Comment: @tagore That is JAVA not PHP, and an entirely different question to what you posted.